# Can DNS sinkhole protection be applied to specific LAN hosts

Tags: ubuntu, dns, bind

I know how to set up a DNS sinkhole that protects all hosts on a LAN, but is there a method of applying different sink hole definitions to different LAN hosts? Or even allow some defined LAN hosts unfettered access to the internet?

My setup is a single machine acting as the gateway/firewall/DNS/DHCP with two NICs, one either side of the firewall. This server is running Ubuntu, bind9.

I can see this may be possible with an additional NIC on the LAN side, using that as an additional internal gateway IP, but let's be restricted to my current setup.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe if you could provide a different DNS server to each host perhaps? (ex. via virtual machines?) But networking that sounds like a hassle. You might simply be better off looking at web proxy like [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/).

Comment: Interesting. Thanks, I'll take a look.